# How to create Instance of my ViewModel Class using ViewModelProvider

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-room

I want to know how can i create an instance of my ViewModel class using **ViewModelProvider** class.I Know how to create an instance of ViewModel class using ViewModelProviders, but now its deprecated .So I cant find any documentation to create an instance of ViewModel class using ViewModelProvider .

I found [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#13) a way to instantiate ViewModel class using ViewModelProviders (But it's not working).Here's the code

`mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);`

Please someone help me .I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

In case if you're using androidx packages, you can initialize your ViewModel class like this:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MyActivity.this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

The android.arch Architecture Components packages are no longer maintained. They have been superseded by the corresponding androidx.* packages.
Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders?hl=en) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

is correct and it does work, your issue might be somewhere else..